# Swift string date to date

Tags: swift, date, nsuserdefaults, nsdateformatter

I read a date from `UserDefaults.standard` as string in the following format:

> "2020-11-06T05:20:20+0100"

I try to convert this string to a date using the following code

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "de_DE")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
let dateString: String! = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "timeShared")
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
```

However, the result is always `nil`. Using `let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)!` explicitly causes a fatal error.

Any ideas what to do?

Comment: Are you sure you have valid data in that `dateString`?

Comment: You have to use locale `en_US_POSIX`, otherwise parsing won't work correctly in all situations.

Comment: Also, this will crash when `dateString` is `nil`. Using an implicitly unwrapped optional is very dangerous in this situation.

Comment: Consider to use `ISO8601DateFormatter`. It decodes this format without any further settings.

Comment: Maybe it would be better to store it as a Date object in UserDefaults?

Comment: Changing to `en_US_POSIX` does not change anything. Printing out `let dateString: String! = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "timeShared")` returns indeed `"2020-11-06T10:00:24+0100"`. `ISO8601DateFormatter` will be tried!

Answer (score 0):

Changing the former code to

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "\"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ\""
```

returns a neatly formatted date subsequently. The error was that the date read from UserDefaults included `""`.

Answer (score 0):

May be `UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "timeShared")` have **no value** or the value is not in **string format** and you are doing force unwrapping in `let dateString: String! = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "timeShared")` here that making the fatal error.

Better add a conditional if, then use the *dateString*.

Refer the below code.

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "de_DE")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
if let dateString: String = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "timeShared") {
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
    print(date)
} else {
    print("Data in UserDefaults: \(UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "timeShared"))")
}
```